# Blank screen after kernel auto-update in Ubuntu 15.10 (from 4.2.0-41.48 to -42.49)

Tags: kernel, updates, xorg, amd-graphics

First time this happens to me since I switched to linux (>1y). When I reboot with the old kernel (-41.48) i get the GUI and all is fine.
Any known issues with that new -42 kernel ? I have a AMD/ATI machine running (64-bit).

Comment: Could you specify a bit more, please?  Exactly when do you get a black screen?  When you should see the grub?  Directly after grub?  After the bootup splash when it should be loading lightdm?

Answer (score 0):

Could be something to do with proprietary drivers; I encountered a similar problem on 16.04 after choosing to use nVidia's proprietary drivers instead of X.Org Server, couldn't login anymore. If you are using proprietary drivers, consider falling back to X.Org, so far I haven't encountered a better solution.

```
$ sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
```

This should work - if you were using proprietary drivers that is